# ¿Como puedo colocar un tiempo máximo de respuesta en una petición http en fluter?

Tags: flutter

Estoy utilizado el paquete http https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http.

```
http.get(URL_SERVICE_BASIC, headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token"
  })
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usar `read` en lugar de `get`,  ese método hace un `get` internamente y retorna el body en `String`.

```
final responseString = http.read("url",headers: {}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
```